# как верстать объект который выходит за сетку бутстрапа

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

вот есть макет в фигме, там объекты выходят за 12-колоночную сетку, как будто там 14 колонок. Как это верстать?
[image]
и как сделать так чтобы полоска в хедере выходила за пределы сетки на немного?

Comment: имхо - в данном случаи просто не правильно стоят сетки. Расширить их до краев контента, и сверху хедеру дать максимальную ширину и отцентрировать.

Comment: Crus, а есть варик контент на css grid сделать? скажем, сам grid в сетку бутстрапа сунуть и потом за края выйти?

Comment: ну извратиться всегда как угодно можно. нужно ли. )  Если делать по сеткам бутстрапа - надо по ним нормально делать )

Comment: Crus, т е нужно сам макет переделать?( а как можно с полоской извратиться? она по-любому должна быть больше чем сетка

Comment: ну, по человечески - контентная область макета не может выпирать за сетки. какая полоска )?

Comment: между хедером и каталогом